# How to create a dialog with custom content like android in Zebble for Xamarin?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-zebble, zebble

I want to create a dialog for editing some field and I need to make custom content for dialog and get the response from it to reload the Data. So, I read all content about dialog and popup in link below

http://zebble.net/docs/alerts-and-dialogs

And then I test this code:

In another page I want to show the popup:

```
await Nav.ShowPopUp<CustomeDialogPage>();
```

My custom Zebble page:

```
<z-Component z-type="CustomeDialogPage" 
         z-base="Page" 
         z-namespace="UI.Pages" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../.zebble-schema.xml">

  <Stack CssClass="customedialog">
     <Button Text="OK" />
  </Stack>  

  </z-Component>
```

And then I create stylesheet for that

```
.customedialog {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

but, I could not able to close the popup or add a title section for it and I do not know how I can get the result of it.
And it is a sample dialog I want to use it like below:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a draft image of what you expect to see on the pop-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zebble provides you with other overloads of the Nav pop-up methods to help you achieve that.

**Host page:**

```
var result = await Nav.ShowPopup<TargetPage, SomeType>();
// Now you can use "result".
```

**Pop-up page's close button:**

```
...
await Nav.HidePopup(someResultValue);
```

Notes:

- "SomeType" can be a simple type such as boolean or string, or it can be a complex class.
- The type of the object returned by the pop-up must match the one expected by the host parent page.

You can check out the full spec here: http://zebble.net/docs/showing-popup-pages